# Change index of a pivoted table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that looks like this-

```
        0
type    A    B   C
obs
x       NA   1   2
y       1    1   2
z       2    2   3
```

I want to reset the index to look like this-

```
obs    A   B   C
x      NA  1   2
y      1   1   2
z      2   2   3
```

Using `reset_index` with `inplace=True` does not work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need remove `[]` in pivot or specify parameter `values` for prevent `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'obs': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'], 
'type': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
0: [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]}
)
#print (df)


print (df.pivot_table(index='obs', columns='type'))
        0          
type    A    B    C
obs                
x     NaN  1.0  2.0
y     1.0  1.0  2.0
z     2.0  2.0  3.0

print (df.pivot_table(index='obs', columns='type', values=[0]))
        0          
type    A    B    C
obs                
x     NaN  1.0  2.0
y     1.0  1.0  2.0
z     2.0  2.0  3.0

print (df.pivot_table(index='obs', columns='type', values=0))

type    A    B    C
obs                
x     NaN  1.0  2.0
y     1.0  1.0  2.0
z     2.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Yet another dupe. Sir you taught me this answer long ago.

Comment: Yes, but find it is not easy for me, because to many answers :(

Comment: In this case, the answer is talking about prevention rather than a cure... there may be a better question to close as a duplicate of, but for now this seems good enough to keep.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Can you reopen this question?

Comment: The duplicate is applicable, but your answer is equally applicable if not more. In this case, it's okay for your answer to remain (in my opinion). If you disagree, you can reopen it.